# Render result shows nothing

Tags: rendering

Trying to make a simple typography animation but when I go to the render tab, nothing shows up

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, nothing shows up? could you post a screenshot of what happens after you do Render > Render image?

Comment: Please notice you have one close vote.